# JSF 1.2 difference between exception in action and actionListener

Tags: java, exception, jsf, action, actionlistener

I've noticed that JSF 1.2. does not return error page when an exception was thrown in actionListener method but does return error page when an exception was thrown in action method. Why is that? Can it return error page in both cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any exception which is thrown in a [`FacesEvent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/event/FacesEvent.html) listener method is silently caught and wrapped in a [`AbortProcessingException`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/event/AbortProcessingException.html) and logged to the console. That's just as per the specification.

The `ActionEvent` listener method (as any other `FacesEvent` listener method) has no responsibility for navigational tasks. The real action method has. Generally, the action listener method should only be used whenever you want to *observe* an action invoke, not to execute some business task (which affects the response).