# Adding cookie in JSF PhaseListener

Tags: http, jsf, cookies

I have a legacy application using JSF version 1.1

I am trying to set a cookie in all responses, but through a `PhaseListener` implementation instead of usual `Filter` because of specific requirement.

I did something like:

```
public class MyPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.ANY_PHASE;
    }

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext
                            .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            int cookieValue = 100;
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("myCookie", "" + cookieValue);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I am checking the responses in chrome dev console, I do not see this cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a JSF phaselistener and not in a servletfilter like most do?

Comment: @Kukeltje: I want to set some value in the cookie which is only available after Faces Servlet has executed. Which will only be happening after ServletFilter.

Comment: Just ['chain'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122870/what-is-the-use-of-filter-and-chain-in-servlet) and set the cookie when you get back in the filter

Comment: @Kukeltje: Sorry for the late response. can you elaborate a bit? Do you mean I set the required value in response, and grab that in filter on the way back, read from response and set as a cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after RENDER_RESPONSE is probably to late, before RENDER_RESPONSE should work fine.

Comment: Hmmm good catch. Might indeed be the reason Otoh, would have expected an error then something like 'response already comitted'

Comment: @tandraschko: I tried the same code in beforePhase method. But I still can not see the cookie at the client side. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would try after INVOKE_APPLICATION then