# JSF UISelectItems HtmlSelectOneListbox binding value TimeZones

Tags: java, jsf, binding, tomcat10, selectonelistbox

*(note: I subclassed jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem and overridden toString, but for now the code below is effectively identical although i will be in future , removing the object search and simply obtaining the value from "listbox" , also be placing an array in init and make static for session bean)* I created a JSF session bean with jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar and apache-tomcat-10.0.12 using **HtmlSelectOneListbox** to show all TimeZone choices (It Works!) , but i find there is very little scope for the initial code infrastructure to work with because some components don't appear to have a pattern of creating them for using them that operates with **UISelectItems** (plural the wrapper of UIselectItem).
Eventually i found some advice on the net that a class with interface **java.util.Map** can be placed into **setValue of UISelectItems** ,*but placing an array of UISelectItem[] into UISelectItems does not operate!*
*Neither does jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem[] get placed into UISelectItems but is put in a "group" that from API docs is a mystery to me how.*
I found from the API doc , to create a suitable array for UISelectItems requires five particular methods must be used compulsory successfully upon UISelectItem to place into UISelectItems (That finally got it operating).
**How is a jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem placed into anything for "binding"** given that if it is in a group or the group can somehow be specified somewhere.
Too, it took me some time to realize there was a system to create the html "option values" and setItemValue with setValue used on UISelectItem allows the server to store a proper matching index of values sent and recieved **K,V**

I know what binding is and I know what binding does, I just did that! (Also in 2010) but...some nice references to other JSF material.
[How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)
This following is extremely helpful but not much of the problem as it does not use binding in f:selectItems.  [JSF-2 f:selectItems with Map does not display itemLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655349/jsf-2-fselectitems-with-map-does-not-display-itemlabel)

The following is used for "value=" with f:selectItems and is **wrong for use in "binding"!**   itemLabel method is a compulsory on UIComponent
[How to populate options of h:selectOneMenu from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database)
Another recommended uses richfaces not jakarta

**This is part of the interesting creature, this extends Object in Jakarta API docs
**jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem** but cannot find a suitable alike to f:selectItems in either API or tag! Also the mimmick for optgroup labelling tag is another difficulty to find anything about in model or jakarta.faces.component.html In DHTML and HTML a "select" tag does not require any option or optgroup(if supported) tags because they can all be inserted in page and managed dynamically, hence a UISelectOneListbox(or other classes produce "select") will render without any nested tags although it has a body tag processor for nested tags**

Someone wanted to see the XHTML page *SOURCE*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view>
 <h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml" />
<meta content="index,follow"  name="robots" />
<meta content="" name="Description" />
<meta content="" name="Keywords" />
<meta content="nicephotog AT gmail.com" name="Author" />
<title>PAGE TITLE</title>
<!--  <link href="CSS-FILE-NAME.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  -->
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/JsfTestApp/newjavascript.js" />  -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
/*   This script written by Samuel A Marchant nicephotog@gmail.com 7th Oct 2023
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

rdx=0;
pass=false;
/*
 function sbm(){
document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
          
 function getSelVal(){
     //alert(""+document.getElementById("bcb").value);
  return document.getElementById("bcb").value;  
 } 
 function setSecval(){
     document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value = getSelVal();
      //alert("[1] "+document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value);
return document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value;         
 }
 */

 function matchIdxforRestart(ire){
  rdx=ire;   
 return rdx;   
 }
 
 function psvL(ps){
 pass=ps;    
 return pass;    
 }
 
 function seledoc(ixnm){
     //alert("ixnm : "+ixnm+"   rdx ");
     matchIdxforRestart(parseInt((ixnm+1)));
 return document.getElementById("fbb:cec").selectedIndex=ixnm;
 }
 
 function findField(){
return document.getElementById("findinlist").value;         
 }
 
 function findmatchingindex(){
 opr = document.getElementById("fbb:cec").options; 
 lin = opr.length;
 
currentword=new String(document.getElementById("findinlist").value).toLowerCase();
//efendi=new String("  ");
efendi=currentword; //debug
afi = "";
or=0;
pass=psvL(false);



hasfound=false; // for stop
/*

if((parseInt(currentword.indexOf(efendi))==-1)){
    efendi=currentword;
matchIdxforRestart(0);  // rdx
or=0;
pass=false;
hasfound=false;
}else{
 if(parseInt(currentword.length)!=parseInt(efendi.length)){
     efendi=currentword;
matchIdxforRestart(0);  // rdx
or=0;
pass=false; 
hasfound=false;
 }else{;}      
}
  */      
 stp=false;       

 while(or<lin && stp==false){
if((rdx!=0) && (rdx<lin) && (pass==false)){
      or=rdx; 
      pass=psvL(true);
}else{;}
 afi=(new String(opr[or].value)).toLowerCase();
  if(afi.indexOf(efendi)!=-1){
  seledoc(parseInt(or));
   pass=psvL(false);
hasfound=true;
   or=lin;
  }else{

      if((or==(lin-1)) && (hasfound==false)){
         stp=true;
          matchIdxforRestart(0);
     }else{
           if(or>(lin-2)){
 matchIdxforRestart(0);
 pass=psvL(false);
 or=0;
 }else{;} 
     }
     
         }

     or++;
 
 } //ewhl

 }//enfunc
   //]]> 
</script>
 </h:head>
     <h:body id="fug" style="background-image: url(bkg.png);font-family:arial;font-size:13pt;margin: 10px;">
            
            
<!--  
created by SUcommanderXer Last Pre Beta www.nicephotog-jsp.net
  -->

<center>
<b>The <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">HttpOutputTools (<i>-----------------</i> "-------------------")</span> Java <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">Jar</span> project</b>
<p />

<!--
worldtime html and hidden jsf
-->

<input type="button" value=" find " onclick="findmatchingindex();" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" id="findinlist" value="" />
<br />

<h:form id="fbb" rendered="true">
    
    <h:selectOneListbox required="true" id="cec" binding="#{selOneLiBox.listBox}" label="World Time Regions" style="font-size: 13pt;width:500px;" value="#{selOneLiBox.currentTimeWorldZone}">
        <f:selectItems rendered="true" binding="#{selOneLiBox.seLits}"  />
    </h:selectOneListbox><br />
    
 <h:commandButton id="sbmtt" action="getmoretime" value="Submit" />
</h:form>

<p />
<h:outputText value="#{selOneLiBox.worldTime}" rendered="true" escape="false" /> 


<p />


<p />




<!--  Put a time and date JSF field in here  , and control to find particular timezone and location e.g. combobox list -->


<div style="padding:10px;width:95%;text-align:left;font-size:10pt;border:rgb(150,150,150) 3px solid;visibility:visible;">
 <b>The <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">HttpOutputTools (------------- "------------")</span> Java <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">Jar</span> project</b>
 <p style="font-style: italic;color: rgb(0,100,0);font-weight: bold;" />
[ Quick note REMEMBER THIS : In a nutshell 99.999r percent of all method calls in code when using the package should be from an interface, classes are only ever directly instantiated from the package if one of three server application scope server memory stored classes are constructed for loading at application init (names ending with 'Obj' that after retrieval with getAttribute() from the server should be cast to / received on an identifier as an interface) or it is the one special class to obtain the Interface 'Tool', the interface used to obtain almost all other interfaces ]
<p />
The HttpOutputTools projects started as a java web server file read/write output mechanism <b>to assist lowering repetitive server side coding overhead of extremely common segments of tasks and being able to setup read (from file) / writes (to output) for tunable conservation of RAM space</b>, particularly for small RAM allocation java servers such as in hosting plans.
<p />
Because many tasks of web server JSP,JSF or Servlet/Web Sevice use code that is repeated but often does require some severe modification for purpose, other library parts were added to build a set of common but short methods to lower repeated method call usage to produce these small common sub parts that occur, too, these methods often require other SE core library classes, resulting requirement for these classes to be used and callable in this package. These were added to the package by method calls to obtain and instantiate and use <i>from the one (or as few as possible) coding identifier</i> in the package rather than completely requiring to set up classes from import statements and instantiation.
<p />
Any reputable or J2EE Java Web Server contains a system to hold in memory special instantiated object classes instaniated at application startup that are obtained from the ServletContext or ApplicationContext. Some of the classes in the package are for use running stored in memory of the Web Server while the application is "on"(running), (However, a side note to this, all classes are Java SE core in the HTToutPutTools package and can be used in a desktop application or anywhere SE Core is used if wanted).
<p />
<span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">The jar package of classes includes:</span>
<p />
<ul>
<li>Hold commonly served documents or images (binary or B64) in memory either permanent or dynamically avoiding file handling.</li>
<li>Read files by "byte" in a small chunk section with self closing either for direct output or encrypted to Base 64 String.</li>
<li>Assess memory usage to assist preventing overrun during heavy server loading to custom trigger the JVM GC if required.</li>
<li>Help code internationalized java.time and form programs doing less coding and some web server relevant time pattern formats for UTC headers.</li>
<li>Text and time internationalization and Locale language testing with encodings, also a vast array of many HTML/XML entities.</li>
<li>Create and manage Cookies for server or page javascript.</li>
<li>Web server header commands list and special characters array for internationalization , header and script or cookies encoding.</li>
<li>Lower coding overhead of web server encoding schemes.</li>
<li>Binary search of byte literals, or byte literals of Strings in file , or with an Ignore Case version.</li>
<li>Storing special custom text "information" dynamically in server memory.</li>
<li>Quickly create or append to files e.g. temp files.</li>
</ul>

<p align="center" style="font-weight:bold;" />
Link: HttpOutPutTools Tutorial &nbsp; &nbsp; Link: HttpOutPutTools API Jar Documentation &nbsp; &nbsp; Link: HttpOutPutTools Sources Download

</div>

</center>

      </h:body>
  </f:view>   
</html>
```

This is what i did and appear the only way to bind to the XHTML tag in page.

```
package beans;

import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
//import jakarta.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import com.nicephotog.tools.*;
import com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj;
import com.nicephotog.tools.wwwtimeifc.WebSqlTimeVar;
import java.util.Locale;

/*
SelOneLiBox.java completed 5th Oct 2023

JSF SelectOneListBox and UISelectItems binding

jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar   apache-tomcat-10.0.12   "nicephotog-web-tools.jar unreleased - Oct 5th 2023"
 */



/**
 *
 * @author samuel A Marchant nicephotog@gmail.com
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SelOneLiBox{
 
public jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox listbox=null;
public jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems useli=null;
public java.util.Map<String,jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem> uiselsB=null;

public String currenttimeworldzone="Australia/ACT";
public String worldtime="none"; 


/*
The best i guess for doing this way is becausethe following require escaping into an XHTML (XML) document
because the ZoneId value String has a forward slash symbol in it . so illegal in xml (nb escaped is false in this)
uiiyinp.setItemValue(pack[pk]);
uiiyinp.setValue(pack[pk]);
*/
public String findZoneObj(){
    String tzfound="";
java.util.Set<String> kys =uiselsB.keySet();
java.util.Iterator<String> io = kys.iterator();   
jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem si = new jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem();
String ishsh ="";
   boolean stp=false;
while((io.hasNext()==true) && (stp==false)){ 
    si=uiselsB.get(io.next()); 
    ishsh =si.toString();
if(ishsh.indexOf(currenttimeworldzone)!=-1){
//setCurrentTimeWorldZone(si.getItemLabel());
tzfound=si.getItemLabel();
stp=true;
}
}//enwhl
return (tzfound);
}//enmeth


public void setCurrentTimeWorldZone(String currentTimeWorldZone){ // setoption    
this.currenttimeworldzone=currentTimeWorldZone;
}   

public String getCurrentTimeWorldZone(){ // setoption
return currenttimeworldzone;
}


public jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems getSeLits(){ // setoption
return useli;
}

public void setSeLits(jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems useli){
this.useli=useli;
}
   
public void setListBox(jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox listbox){
if(listbox!=null){}else{
this.listbox=makelistbox();
}
this.listbox=listbox;
}  
 
// NOTE encodeBegin e.t.c. methods are for outputing in a servlet string dynamically with a reference to the Faces servlet dynamically
public jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox getListBox(){ // for h:text
if(listbox!=null){
listbox.saveState(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
}else{
this.listbox=makelistbox();
}
return listbox;   
}



public jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem makeSel(String pack,int pk){
jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem uiiyinp = new jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem();
uiiyinp.setItemDescription("World zone ID choice "+pk);
uiiyinp.setItemLabel(pack);
uiiyinp.setItemDisabled(false);
uiiyinp.setItemEscaped(false);
uiiyinp.setItemValue(pack);
uiiyinp.setValue(pack);
uiiyinp.setRendered(true);
return (uiiyinp);
} 

public jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox makelistbox(){ // for h:text
listbox = new jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox();

String[] pack = obtainZoneIDarray();
int pck = pack.length;

uiselsB = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<String,jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem>();

jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem buiiyinp = new jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem();

for(int pk=0;pk<pck;pk++){
buiiyinp = makeSel(pack[pk],pk);
//uiiyinp.setId(""+pack[pk]); String does not conform
buiiyinp.setParent(useli);  
uiselsB.put(pack[pk],buiiyinp);
        }//enfr
useli = new jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems();
useli.setValue(uiselsB);
listbox.setSize(10);
listbox.setRendered(true);
listbox.saveState(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());

return (listbox);   
} 


//    com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.objattrifc    ZoneIdAndLocalelObjAttr     getStringZoneIDArray()
//   class com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj    getAttribute()    getTZoneIdLocalesArrayObjRef()
// NOTE following array should be stored in an Application scoped bean
public String[] obtainZoneIDarray(){
ServletContext appconxt = (jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext().getContext();
return ((((WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj)appconxt.getAttribute("ConstantsObj")).getTZoneIdLocalesArrayObjRef()).getStringZoneIDArray());
}



public String getWorldTime(){
String tz = findZoneObj();
if(tz.length()<1){
tz=currenttimeworldzone; // bare value at loading of bean - then everything after is findZoneObj() object ID search and itemlabel
}
    String tm = "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:15pt;\">";
    try{
Tool tl = new ToolWww().getWwwTool();
WebSqlTimeVar wbsqtm = tl.getTimeStampPodNow();
wbsqtm.setThisZoneidObj(java.time.ZoneId.of(tz));
tm += "JSF ListBox : "+wbsqtm .getDayOfWeek(Locale.US)+" "+wbsqtm.getYYYYMMDD(true)+" "+wbsqtm.getHHMMSS()+" "+tz+" </span>";
    }catch(Exception ecx){
    System.out.println("Error in JSF bean WorldTimeBean getWorldTime()");
    }
worldtime=tm;
 return worldtime;   
}

    
}//enclss
```

This is the XHTML page somewhat expigated

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml" />
<meta content="index,follow" name="robots" />
<meta content="" name="Description" />
<meta content="" name="Keywords" />
<meta content="nicephotog AT gmail.com" name="Author" />
<title>PAGE TITLE</title>
<!--  &lt;link href="CSS-FILE-NAME.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /&gt;  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sbm(){
document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
          
 function getSelVal(){
     //alert(""+document.getElementById("bcb").value);
  return document.getElementById("bcb").value;  
 } 
 function setSecval(){
     document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value = getSelVal();
      //alert("[1] "+document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value);
return document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value;         
 }
          
    </script></head><body id="fug" style="background-image: url(bkg.png);font-family:arial;font-size:13pt;margin: 10px;">
            
            
<!--  
created by SUcommanderXer Last Pre Beta www.nicephotog-jsp.net
  -->

<center>
<b>The <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">HttpOutputTools (<i>-----------------</i> "-------------------")</span> Java <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">Jar</span> project</b>
<p></p>

<!--
worldtime html and hidden jsf
-->
<form id="fbb" name="fbb" method="post" action="/JsfTestApp/faces/newbasefile.xhtml;jsessionid=3F8D963E42CFE75ACC715C99EA214211" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="fbb" value="fbb" />
<select id="fbb:cec" name="fbb:cec" size="10" style="font-size: 13pt;width:500px;"> <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@69c63b36">Asia/Aden</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@2cc4a86a">America/Cuiaba</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@3de961d4">Etc/GMT+9</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@1d22a712">Etc/GMT+8</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@45e5300b">Africa/Nairobi</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@4ceb5725">America/Marigot</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@3a7a78ad">Asia/Aqtau</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@326852c7">Pacific/Kwajalein</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@5ee159e9">America/El_Salvador</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@48a56f6f">Asia/Pontianak</option>

    <!--
    MANY MANY MORE OPTIONS BETWEEN

    -->
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@6b2b64f5">Pacific/Majuro</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@415c8d4e">America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@b9d93">Europe/Nicosia</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@6dabb6ab">Pacific/Guadalcanal</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@5d177b27">Europe/Athens</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@7804ab36">US/Pacific</option>
    <option value="jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem@24bf56a0">Europe/Monaco</option>
</select><input id="fbb:sbmtt" type="submit" name="fbb:sbmtt" value="Submit" /><input type="hidden" name="jakarta.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:jakarta.faces.ViewState:0" value="1335364430110979657:2013716172780036343" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

<p></p><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:15pt;">JSF ListBox : Friday 2023-10-06 13:08:39 Australia/ACT </span> 


<p></p>


<p></p>




<!--  Put a time and date JSF field in here  , and control to find particular timezone and location e.g. combobox list -->


<div style="padding:10px;width:95%;text-align:left;font-size:10pt;border:rgb(150,150,150) 3px solid;visibility:visible;">
 <b>The <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">HttpOutputTools (------------- "------------")</span> Java <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">Jar</span> project</b>

 <!--  OTHER INFO TEXT IN MARKUP  ->


<p align="center" style="font-weight:bold;"></p>
Link: HttpOutPutTools Tutorial     Link: HttpOutPutTools API Jar Documentation     Link: HttpOutPutTools Sources Download

</div>

</center></body>   
</html>
```

Here is an image of it all

[image: xhtml jsf page output]

I tried inserting the array of UISelectItem f:SelectItems tag by method and tried array of jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem to f:SelectItems tag and as f:SelectItems tag value but only java.util.Map succeeds.

Comment: That looks like the output of your program, can you include your actual XHTML?

Comment: THE XHTM IS BELOW THE JAVA CODE                           NB: Ignore the javascript in the XHTML page , it is for a different JSF form that uses an HTML markup select tag and options to a hidden JSF form field field, it's not this one.

Comment: I think you've gone down a long and unfortunately incorrect path - that XHTML doesn't use any of the JSF tags, it's not this hard to bind items to a drop down. You might benefit from checking out another JSF tutorial.

Comment: h:head and h:body are there and the namespaces in the html tag but this is the best without finding an "edit button" for the post. It all operates , its simply other classes more specific to html don't appear to be usable, niether the UISelectItem as an array of them.

Comment: @BalusC often it's ok to hand over the .java or .class or jar, but it is extremely unpractical to edit (other people or organisation) pages hence just one attribute binding= makes sense.

Comment: @BalusC unfortunately a comment in the code was wiped at the top read  basically "components array for f:selectItems should be in an Application's coped bean" but I could also build an extra class for my tools as standard to hold String[] arrays alike textvarstore.

Comment: Just found jakarta.faces.model.SelectItemGroup masquerades as a     jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem because it does the "optgroup tag" and encases an array of the selectItems. Now to find a tag for binding or value for the jakarta.faces.model. version because SelectItem is not UIComponent although UISelectOne does have setGroup and  jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox does extend from UISelectOne

Comment: I had to properly debug the script (it's changed and valid code or=-1 and rdx=0 if the last index is a match into seledoc() , has found in that here requires returning global and many new safetys) BUT , I'll now use the model.SelectItem and if goes well can offer Boolean checkbox for search by script or search by server and bring back relevant results into the html select listbox and use display names not the zoneid strings, also I can use the array from my server framework better, may be no need for static array for multiple bean instances.

Comment: Found it the array in my framework is doing something odd!   Getting a problem initialising arrays in static init block.  RE STRANGE NULL joined to the array variable in system out println test however it prints the value immediately joined to it E.g .  "nullTahiti time". The second static array to   be initialised does not get that problem and the SelectItem (single each) do not use the variables with the null joined everything operates all except ok!

Comment: Line 149 TimeIDandLocale in http outputtools Jat had a +  symbol in front of the initialising variable do was adding null plus the value to string! Recompiling the jar.

Answer (score 0):

No one would like to answer their own *question and basically it remains standing in part of it relating
**jakarta.faces.model.SelectItemGroup** that becomes far more confusing* than switching between java.util.Map<String,jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem> to the jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem system.

To make it more efficient i initialized all of it in a static block except the list box because it will with its value require to be an "instance".

The real difference when using jakarta.faces.component.**UISelectItems** with jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem[] **as array** is it will then operate , **but not for the UISelectIems if it is an array** , UISelectItems must be a java.util.Map!

(Completed Oct 29 corrected property name, changed SelectItems() to static and null on set, a rule bend - knocks out 50Kb data each copy - works fine now )

Main code

```
package beans;

import jakarta.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
//import jakarta.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import jakarta.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import com.nicephotog.tools.*;
import com.nicephotog.tools.objectattribute.WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj;
import com.nicephotog.tools.wwwtimeifc.WebSqlTimeVar;
import java.util.Locale;

/*
SelOneLiBox.java completed October 29th 2023 ( changed to have selectitems array static store variable  approx. 50kb data and null global property variable as set )
JSF SelectOneListBox and UISelectItems binding
jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar   apache-tomcat-10.0.12   "nicephotog-web-tools.jar unreleased - Oct 5th 2023"
 */

/**
 *
 * @author samuel A Marchant nicephotog@gmail.com
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SelOneLiBox{
public static final int arrznln;
//public static final String[] dspnam; // if you want final use a "constructor"
//public static final String[] zonval;
public static final jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem[] allzone;
public static final boolean rendT=true;
public static final boolean disaB=false;
public static final boolean escp=false;
public static final boolean noseloP=false;
//private static final jakarta.faces.model.SelectItemGroup[] allzonechoices;
public static jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems sLs=null;
public jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems seLits=null;
public jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox listbox=null; // setCurrentTimeWorldZone(listbox.getValue().toString());
//public java.util.Map<String,jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItem> uiselsB=null;
public String currenttimeworldzone="Australia/ACT";
public String worldtime="none"; 

static{
arrznln = ((((WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj)((jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext().getContext()).getAttribute("ConstantsObj")).getTZoneIdLocalesArrayObjRef()).lengthArrayZoneIdObject());
String[] dspnam=((((WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj)((jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext().getContext()).getAttribute("ConstantsObj")).getTZoneIdLocalesArrayObjRef()).getZoneIDNameTextArray());
String[] zonval=((((WebAppToolAPIconstantsObj)((jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext().getContext()).getAttribute("ConstantsObj")).getTZoneIdLocalesArrayObjRef()).getStringZoneIDArray());
allzone = new jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem[arrznln];
String reconstr="";
for(int init=0;init<arrznln;init++){
reconstr=new String((zonval[init]+"  - "+dspnam[init]+" -").getBytes());
allzone[init]=new SelectItemStringer();
allzone[init].setValue(zonval[init]);
allzone[init].setLabel(reconstr);
allzone[init].setDescription("zoneID choice");
allzone[init].setDisabled(disaB);
allzone[init].setEscape(escp);
//allzone[init].setNoSelectionOption(noseloP);
}//enfr
//allzonechoices = new jakarta.faces.model.SelectItemGroup("All ZoneID Choices","All ZoneID Choices",false,allzone);
sLs = new jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems();
sLs.setValue(allzone);
}//enstat

/*
private static String[] putstrdspnm(String[] ip){
dspnam=ip;
return dspnam;
}

//zonval dspnam
private static String[] putstrzonam(String[] ip){
zonval=ip;
return zonval;
}
*/




public void setCurrentTimeWorldZone(String currentTimeWorldZone){ // setoption    
this.currenttimeworldzone=currentTimeWorldZone;
}   

public String getCurrentTimeWorldZone(){ // setoption
return currenttimeworldzone;
}




public void setSeLits(jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems seLits){ // setoption
this.seLits=null;
}


public jakarta.faces.component.UISelectItems getSeLits(){ // setoption
    seLits=sLs;
return seLits;
}
   
public void setListBox(jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox listbox){
this.listbox=listbox;
}  
 
// NOTE encodeBegin e.t.c. methods are for outputing in a servlet string dynamically with a reference to the Faces servlet dynamically
public jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox getListBox(){ // for h:text
if(listbox!=null){ 
listbox.saveState(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
}else{
this.listbox=makelistbox();
}
return listbox;   
}


/*
-- groups to make
America
Etc
Africa
Asia
Pacific
Indian
Europe
GMT
Australia
Canada
Atlantic
US
--Anything Else--
*/
public jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox makelistbox(){ // for h:text
listbox = new jakarta.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneListbox();
listbox.setLabel("World Time Zone Localities");
listbox.setSize(10);
listbox.setRendered(true);
listbox.saveState(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
return listbox;   
} 


public String getWorldTime(){
    String tm = "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:15pt;\">";
    try{
Tool tl = new ToolWww().getWwwTool();
WebSqlTimeVar wbsqtm = tl.getTimeStampPodNow();
wbsqtm.setThisZoneidObj(java.time.ZoneId.of(currenttimeworldzone));
tm += "JSF ListBox : "+wbsqtm.getDayOfWeek(java.util.Locale.US)+" "+wbsqtm.getYYYYMMDD(true)+" "+wbsqtm.getHHMMSS()+" "+currenttimeworldzone+" </span>";
    }catch(Exception ecx){
    System.out.println("Error in JSF bean WorldTimeBean getWorldTime()");
    }
worldtime=tm;
 return worldtime;   
}//enmeth

    
}//enclss
```

toString Class code to extend from each selectitem

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package beans;

/**
 *
 * @author samuel
 */
public class SelectItemStringer extends jakarta.faces.model.SelectItem{

public SelectItemStringer(){
super();
}

@Override
public String toString(){
return (String) super.getValue();
}
    
}//enclss
```

The XHTML JSF page source Completely corrected blips in the js

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <f:view>
 <h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml" />
<meta content="index,follow"  name="robots" />
<meta content="" name="Description" />
<meta content="" name="Keywords" />
<meta content="nicephotog AT gmail.com" name="Author" />
<title>PAGE TITLE</title>
<!--  <link href="CSS-FILE-NAME.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />  -->
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/JsfTestApp/newjavascript.js" />  -->
<style type="text/css">
    li{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
/*   This script written by Samuel A Marchant nicephotog@gmail.com 10th Oct 2023
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
efendi=new String(" ");
rdx=0;
pass=false;
hasfound=false;
/*
 function sbm(){
document.forms[0].submit(); 
}
          
 function getSelVal(){
     //alert(""+document.getElementById("bcb").value);
  return document.getElementById("bcb").value;  
 } 
 function setSecval(){
     document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value = getSelVal();
      //alert("[1] "+document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value);
return document.getElementById("fmm:selhide").value;         
 }
 */

function fndi(fstr){
 efendi=fstr;   
 return efendi;   
}


 function matchIdxforRestart(ire){
  rdx=ire;   
 return rdx;   
 }
 
 function psvL(ps){
 pass=ps;    
 return pass;    
 }
 
 function seledoc(ixnm){
     //alert("ixnm : "+ixnm+"   rdx ");
     matchIdxforRestart(parseInt((ixnm+1)));
 return document.getElementById("fbb:cec").selectedIndex=ixnm;
 }
 
 function findField(){
return document.getElementById("findinlist").value;         
 }
 
 function adjHasfound(hsf){
  hasfound=hsf;
  return hasfound;
 }
 
 function findmatchingindex(){
 opr = document.getElementById("fbb:cec").options; 
 lin = opr.length;
currentword=new String(document.getElementById("findinlist").value).toLowerCase();
afi = "";
or=0; // while
pass=psvL(false);

 
if((currentword.length > 3) || (currentword.indexOf("us")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("uct")!=-1)|| (currentword.indexOf("sao")!=-1)|| (currentword.indexOf("tel")!=-1)|| (currentword.indexOf("rio")!=-1)|| (currentword.indexOf("boa")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("dar")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("la")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("st")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("snt")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("el")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("san")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("cet")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("gmt")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("gb")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("etc")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("utc")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("rok")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("met")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("nz")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("prc")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("wet")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("eet")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("+")!=-1) || (currentword.indexOf("-")!=-1)){ 

// BUT IF YOU HAVE FOUND THEN YOU START TO SEARCH FROM rdx NOT ZERO INDEX corrects start position
 if((currentword.indexOf(efendi)==-1) || ((efendi.length==currentword.length) && (efendi.indexOf(currentword)==-1)) || (efendi.length!=currentword.length)){
fndi(currentword); //     efendi=   
matchIdxforRestart(0);
adjHasfound(false);
 }else{;}
 
 stp=false; 
 while((or<lin) && (stp==false)){
if((rdx!=0) && (rdx<lin) && (pass==false)){
      or=rdx; 
      psvL(true);
}else{;}
 afi=(new String(opr[or].value)).toLowerCase();
  if(afi.indexOf(efendi)!=-1){
  seledoc(parseInt(or));
   psvL(false);
adjHasfound(true);
   or=lin;
  }else{

      if((or==(lin-1)) && (hasfound==false)){
         stp=true;
          matchIdxforRestart(0);
     }else{
           if(or>(lin-2)){
 matchIdxforRestart(0);
 psvL(false);
 or=-1;
 }else{;} 
     }
         }
     or++;
 } //ewhl

 
}else{
 alert("Error: Please use minimum 4 characters - Word length too short  "+efendi);       
}

 }//enfunc
   //]]> 
</script>
 </h:head>
     <h:body id="fug" style="background-image:url('../bkg.jpg');font-family:arial;font-size:13pt;margin: 10px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
//    <![CDATA[
// JSF /faces/ background url syntax
 //   alert(""+document.getElementById("fug").style.backgroundImage);            
 //          ]]> 
</script>
<!--  
created by SUcommanderXer Last Pre Beta www.nicephotog-jsp.net
  -->

<center>
<b>The <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">HttpOutputTools (<i>Version: Giant Fishing Spider</i> "Anclometes Rufus")</span> Java <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">Jar</span> project</b>
<p />

<!--
worldtime html and hidden jsf
-->

<input type="button" value=" find " onclick="findmatchingindex();" /> &nbsp; <input type="text" id="findinlist" value="" />
<br />Note: Although can be found by local name , for some reason the following display name text does not get found by the script
<br />Eastern Greenland Time (America/Scoresbysund) can be found after GMT+10
<br />Western Greenland Time (America/Nuuk) can be found after GMT-11
<p/> 


<h:form id="fbb" rendered="true">
    
    <h:selectOneListbox required="true" id="cec" binding="#{selOneLiBox.listBox}" label="World Time Regions" style="font-size: 13pt;width:500px;" value="#{selOneLiBox.currentTimeWorldZone}">
        <f:selectItems rendered="true" binding="#{selOneLiBox.seLits}"  />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
   
 <h:commandButton id="sbmtt" action="getmoretime" value="Submit" />
</h:form>

<p />
<h:outputText value="#{selOneLiBox.worldTime}" rendered="true" escape="false" /> 


<p />

<p />
<!--  Put a time and date JSF field in here  , and control to find particular timezone and location e.g. combobox list -->


<div style="padding:10px;width:95%;text-align:left;font-size:10pt;border:rgb(150,150,150) 3px solid;visibility:visible;">
 <b>The <span style="color:rgb(230,50,0);font-style:italic;">HttpOutputTools (<i>Version: Giant Fishing Spider</i> "Anclometes Rufus")</span> Java <span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;">Jar</span> project</b>
 <p />
<span  style="font-style: italic;color: rgb(0,100,0);font-weight: bold;">[ Quick note REMEMBER THIS : In a nutshell 99.999r percent of all method calls in code when using the package should be from an interface, classes are only ever directly instantiated from the package if one of three server application scope server memory stored classes are constructed for loading at application init (names ending with 'Obj' that after retrieval with getAttribute() from the server should be cast to / received on an identifier as it's original class name ending with "...Obj")
    <br />...OR... it is the one special class to obtain the Interface 'Tool', the interface used to obtain almost all other interfaces, the class ToolWww with only one method getWwwTool() ]</span>
<p />
<b>
    <u>There are two pre requisites for use of this jar tool</u> &nbsp;  &nbsp; [Link: Java web Servers and Technologies list]<br />
1. A basic understanding of configuration and tuning of a Java web server e.g. Jakarta Tomcat 10 , Oracle Glassfish 4 or 5<br />
2. A basic understanding of Java Web Server programming for JSP, JSF and Servlet Web Applications</b>
<p />
The HttpOutputTools projects started as a java web server file read/write output mechanism <b>to assist lowering repetitive server side coding overhead of extremely common segments of tasks and being able to setup read (from file) / writes (to output) for tunable conservation of RAM space</b>, particularly for small RAM allocation java servers such as in hosting plans.
<p />
Because many tasks of web server JSP,JSF or Servlet/Web Sevice use code that is repeated but often does require some severe modification for purpose, other library parts were added to build a set of common but short methods to lower repeated method call usage to produce these small common sub parts that occur, too, these methods often require other SE core library classes, resulting requirement for these classes to be used and callable in this package. These were added to the package by method calls to obtain and instantiate and use <i>from the one (or as few as possible) coding identifier</i> in the package rather than completely requiring to set up classes from import statements and instantiation.
<p />
Any reputable or J2EE Java Web Server contains a system to hold in memory special instantiated object classes instaniated at application startup that are obtained from the ServletContext or ApplicationContext. Some of the classes in the package are for use running stored in memory of the Web Server while the application is "on"(running), (However, a side note to this, all classes are Java SE core in the HTTPoutPutTools package and can be used in a desktop application or anywhere SE Core is used if wanted).
<p />
<span style="color:rgb(250,80,0);font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;">The jar package of classes includes the following:</span>
<p />
<ul>
<li>Hold commonly served documents or images (binary or B64) in memory either permanent or dynamically avoiding file handling.</li>
<li>Read files by "byte" in a small chunk section with self closing either for direct output or encrypted to Base 64 String.</li>
<li>Assess memory usage to assist preventing overrun during heavy server loading to custom trigger the JVM GC if required.</li>
<li>Help code internationalized java.time and form programs doing less coding and some web server relevant time pattern formats for UTC headers.</li>
<li>Text and time internationalization and Locale language testing with encodings, also a vast array of many HTML/XML entities.</li>
<li>Create and manage Cookies for server or page javascript.</li>
<li>Web server header commands list and special characters array for internationalization , header and script or cookies encoding.</li>
<li>Lower coding overhead of web server encoding schemes.</li>
<li>Binary byte match search of files by byte literals, or with an Ignore Case byte literal search version if searching for strings in text files.</li>
<li>Storing special custom text "information" dynamically in server memory.</li>
<li>Quickly create or append to files e.g. temp files.</li>
</ul>

<p align="center" style="font-weight:bold;" />
Link: HttpOutPutTools Tutorial &nbsp; &nbsp; Link: HttpOutPutTools API Jar Documentation &nbsp; &nbsp; Link: HttpOutPutTools Sources Download

</div>

</center>

      </h:body>
  </f:view>   
</html>
```

And the ouput page image

[image]

Comment: (in the picture) The note at the top of the page is for the java.util.Map version, the array probably is sorted different order! Of  effect the JavaScript finds perfectly but it does not respond to some words and without error, perhaps a js engine bug . It will find in the same option but not sone words(weird).

Comment: Above is truly "bent" to null the instance that way, found the piece I needed get the session bean in an after phase event to null the non static version.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438869/how-to-retrieve-a-session-scoped-managed-bean-in-a-phaselistener

Comment: LEARNT something great about the h:selectItems list for how I need to do this. The memory for the printed options list and hence any variable holding its state is "in this" approx 50KB makes for 1000 indiv user machines session beans 50000kb. Static was used but must assign to another variable "the property" AND have set method using "binding" . Use value= and the prop set method can be dropped ! Then only get is req. for prop var and should be no requirement for after phase listener to null anything! (Cannot have static set method) Is the real problem with binding "save state" about set ?